# Python pymssql error "TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable" when connecting to SQL server

Tags: python, pymssql

I am getting the error "TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable" when attempting to connect to a SQL server. I believe the error is being generated on the line where I connect to the SQL server itself, as my second print statement is never used, though I could be wrong.

I am using pymysql-2.1.3, and python 3.5.1

```
server = getenv("####")
user = getenv("####")
password = getenv("####")
database = getenv("####")

print("hi")
conn = pymssql.connect(server, user, password, database)
print("hi2")
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("####"
               "SELECT Name, SourceTable, SourceTableID FROM dbo.Attachment WHERE Name LIKE '%icad%'")


conn.close()
print("Connect to SQL complete")
```

This then results in the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
hi
  File "C:/convert.py", line 62, in <module>
    connect_to_sql()
  File "C:convert.py", line 15, in connect_to_sql
    conn = pymssql.connect(server, user, password, database)
  File "pymssql.pyx", line 635, in pymssql.connect (pymssql.c:10734)
  File "_mssql.pyx", line 1902, in _mssql.connect (_mssql.c:21821)
  File "_mssql.pyx", line 552, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.__init__ (_mssql.c:5891)
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have no idea why this is happening - the connect function follows the pymssql documentation exactly.

I am importing the following libraries if it helps:

```
import os
from os import getenv
import pymssql
import subprocess
```

I have removed the database credentials in this question, however I know they work as I am able to connect to the SQL server via the management studio.

Does anyone know why this code doesn't work?

This code is contained within a function called 'connect_to_sql():' and is then used afterwards, however some of the following code is sensitive so I have only cut these particular lines out. I hope it is enough.

Comment: Are you using version 2.x of pymssql?

Comment: Yes, the version I am using is pymssql-2.1.3. Updating question.

Comment: Have you tried to print out the credentials before calling pymssql.connect()? Maybe you are passing something unexpected

Comment: I had assumed that getenv(###) was working, but you know what they say about assuming..

I was actually passing 'None' as the credentials. Removing 'getenv()' solved the issue. Thanks for suggesting that, it's saved me an afternoon of headaches.

Comment: Glad I could help =)

Comment: In fact if you look at the stacktrace it sais `File "_mssql.pyx", line 552, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.__init__ `, you can look it up [here](https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/blob/master/src/_mssql.pyx#L552), then `TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable` tells us that server is None

Answer (score 5):

When the code execution reaches

```
conn = pymssql.connect(server, user, password, database)
```

this error is thrown because **value of server is 'None'**

You have already set the value for this at

```
server = getenv("####")
```

but many at times it so happens that **getenv fails** and returns none.  This is system/platform dependent (especially Windows systems)

You could try printing out values for server and user

```
server = getenv("####")
print(server)
user = getenv("####")
print(user)
```

My experience has been, they return None, hence the connection does not go through.  Since the error is not clear, we tend to assume issue is at connection.